# React router Link or browserHistory.push change url in the address bar but don't redirect from the page with dynamic params in it's url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have the sidebar with react-router Links in it. Purpose of one of the buttons is to redirect logged in user to his profile page with url like /user/:user_id

I defined some logic for that link and it works perfectly without any problems in almost all cases. Here's how it looks like:

```
export class SideBar extends React.Component {
    // ... some omitted code here ...
    getProfileUrlString() {
        /* Function for 'to' attribute of profile Link button in the sidebar.
         * Returns user's profile URL if he's logged in,
         * otherwise redirects him to the /login page
         */
        if (localStorage['token']) {
            return `/user/${localStorage['id']}/`
        } else {
            return '/login'
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper" role="navigation">
            <ul className="sidebar-nav">
                <li><Link onlyActiveOnIndex activeStyle={{color: "#53acff"}} 
                    to="/">Home</Link></li>
                <li><Link onlyActiveOnIndex activeStyle={{color: "#53acff"}} 
                    to={this.getProfileUrlString()}>Profile</Link></li>
                {this.renderSignOutBtn()}
            </ul>
        </div>
      );
    }
}
```

It is my router:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  (<Router history = {browserHistory}>
      <Route path = "/" component = {APP}>
         <IndexRoute component = {Home} />
         <Route path = "home" component = {Home}/>
         <Route path = "/login" component = {LoginComponent} />
         <Route path = "/registration" component = {RegistrationComponent} />
         <Route path = "/user/:user_id" component = {Profile} />
      </Route>
  </Router>),
  document.getElementById('app'));
```

Let's say I have an account and id is 102 so mine profile page is available at `/user/102`

When I visit non-dynamic urls like '/' or '/login' and then click on the Profile Link in the navbar it works perfectly! It successfully redirects me to my profile. But when I visit page of some other user with url like /user/5 and click on Profile link to get back nothing happens! Except one strange thing: url in the address bar changes from /user/5 to /user/102. But profile's component doesn't rerender and all data of user number 5 is in front of me.

I tried to redefine some logic for onClick event and to assign browserHistory.push redirections but there is the same problem too. I tried this.history.push too with the same result.

How can I redirect to the page with dynamic ids in it's url from similar page with similar dynamic params?

React: 15.3.2

react-router: 2.8.1

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: @Polyakoff Nope, problem still exists. I did a hack and now page refreshes when someone clicks that link, but it is not SPA solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should try handling the authentication check in your `routes.js`. This way you can do this check outside of the component by setting the `onEnter` prop of the Route. You can handle all auth checks in one place. You also don't need the `:user_id` in the path.

```
// Routes.js

function requireLogin() {
  if (!localStorage['token']) {
    browserHistory.push('/login');
  }
};

<Route path="/user" component={Profile} onEnter={requireLogin} />
```

Then in your `SideBar` component, just redirect to `/user` all the time.

```
<li>
  <Link onlyActiveOnIndex activeStyle={{color: "#53acff"}} to="/user">Profile</Link>
</li>
```

Then in your `Profile` component, load the user data using  `localStorage['id']` in your `componentDidMount()` function.