# React JS redirecting to another page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm facing the same exact issue as covered in the following, but it still remains unanswered.

[React router Link or browserHistory.push change url in the address bar but don't redirect from the page with dynamic params in it's url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40909482/react-router-link-or-browserhistory-push-change-url-in-the-address-bar-but-dont)

Any leads will be really appreciated. Much thanks.